# Seeding database from YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm  ruby-newbie and i need to seed my database from YAML. After loading YAML  in seeds.rb i got this array of hash :

```
{"projects"=>[{"title"=>"Family", "todos"=>[{"text"=>"buy a milk", "isCompleted"=>false},
 {"text"=>"Change oil in engine", "isCompleted"=>false},
 {"text"=>"To send the letter", "isCompleted"=>true},
 {"text"=>"To drink smt", "isCompleted"=>false}, {"text"=>"Buy t-shirt", "isCompleted"=>false}]},
 {"title"=>"Job", "todos"=>[{"text"=>"Call chief", "isCompleted"=>true},
 {"text"=>"To send documents", "isCompleted"=>true},
 {"text"=>"Make todolist", "isCompleted"=>false}]},
 {"title"=>"Other", "todos"=>[{"text"=>"To call friend", "isCompleted"=>false},
 {"text"=>"Prepare for trip", "isCompleted"=>false}]}]}
```

My code:

```
seed_file = Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds', 'seeds.yml')
config = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML::load_file(seed_file))
```

How i can iterate it and create new Projects and Todos? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to iterate each of the projects and todos:

Let `my_hash` be set to that hash you have, then

```
my_hash[“projects”].each do |project|

  # do whatever you need to do with each item in the hash e.g.
  puts project[“title”]

  # then to get the todos…
  project[“todos”].each do |todo|
    puts todo[“text”]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to put your YAML seed files in db/seeds/, then put this in your db/seeds.rb file:

```
require 'active_record/fixtures'

seeds_dir = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds')
seed_files = Dir["#{seeds_dir}/**/*.yml"].map {|f| f[(seeds_dir.size + 1)..-5] }
ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures(seeds_dir, seed_files)
```

That will load all of your seeds the same way that fixtures are loaded during tests.